# File.CopyTo interprets file as directory

Tags: c#, file, exception, copy

First time I've come across this...

I am trying to copy a generated MSI to a different location.

MSI name (format):
Test.UI.Project.msi

```
string destination = @"C:\TestPath\Test.UI.Project.msi";
FileInfo source = new FileInfo(@"C:\SourcePath\Test.UI.Project.msi");

source.CopyTo(destination, true);
```

This results in

```
System.IO.IOException: The target file "C:\TestPath\Test.UI.Project.msi" is a directory, not a file.
```

This works for other file types, e.g. .dll.

Any ideas?

Comment: This works if you omit the ".", the framework somehow interprets the combination of .msi with that file name as a directory

Comment: Have you tried using file.Copy() instead of fileinfo.CopyTo()

Answer (score 1):

Use Copy and the boolean in the last parameter enables overwrite.

```
File.Copy(@"C:\SourcePath\Test.UI.Project.msi",@"C:\TestPath\Test.UI.Project.msi", true);
```

Comment: Same result...
    System.IO.IOException: The target file "C:\TestPath\Test.UI.Project.msi" is a directory, not a file.

Comment: @NubieJ : check the path with  if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))

Comment: Not going to help.
All that will happen is it will determine the target path does not exist and then will create a folder with the name "Test.UI.Project.msi" after which the copy fails

Answer (score 0):

Non issue - it seems a folder was previously created with that name...
So the copy was not failing due to the name structure, but because there was a folder with the same name in the destination